# Limitations with effect sizes and confidence intervals (fixed effects) with lmer and effectsize in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, lm

*Background*
I've been running a couple of lmer() models with different data and noticed something I cannot really grasp.

The models range from simple to more complicated
(e.g. DV ~ continous_between_Case_Variable + categorical_within_Case_Variable + categorical_between_Case_Variable + (1|Case) )

Given the categorical predictors I am using the anova() function on the lmer() object, to assess if the variable is relevant/significant.
For comparison purposes, I also extract eta² and its confidence intervals (using effectsize::eta_squared).

*Problem*
I noticed that sometimes, when there is clearly no effect, the Pr(>F)/p-value is very high, even 1. However, for some reason, Eta² is sometimes 1 in these cases.

In other cases (independent on the p-value) I noticed that the Confidence intervals range from 0 to another value, or even 0 to 0.

**So my questions are:**

How can I extract Eta² and its confidence intervals more reliably?
I need to know which values I can interpret and which ones I should better replace with NA.

Do I need worry if the confidence interval starts at 0 (which usually goes together with asymmetrical confidence intervals around the estimate)?

Does a confidence interval ranging from 0 to 0 always indicate that it could not be determined and is infinite? But why not simply replacing it then with the largest possible value 1?